# How can I import/export csv using http through Java Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, asp.net, apache, httpclient, reportviewer2008

i have asp.net application,, that have 1 url to open the report,, 
i want to try to export this report using apache http client.,

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     try {

         /* POST login */
         HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:80");

         List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "e"));
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "password"));

         httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
         EntityUtils.consume(entity);

         /* get content*/
         HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:80/Report);

         System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

         // Create a response handler
         ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
         String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
         System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
         System.out.println(responseBody);
         System.out.println("----------------------------------------");


     } finally {
         // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
         // shut down the connection manager to ensure
         // immediate deallocation of all system resources
         httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     }
 }
```

lets say that localhost:80/Report is the report page,, 
and there will be 1 button that export the report to csv.,, and to do that,, i need report session and control id,, 
and after some research,, if i click the export to csv i will get this get method 
"/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=(need this)Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=(need this)&OpType=Export&FileName=Report+Name&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=CSV"

1. how to get report session and control id?
2. how to export the report? i already change the HttpGet into the get method within the same session and control id,but still not working..

am i doing this right? because i'm a totally new in apache httpclient..

Comment: A better way/design to do it, make a web service in asp.net which expose the csv export method, which you can call easily.

Comment: @UmairSaleem i can't do that. in this case, i'm not allowed to change or add any code to the asp.net application.

Comment: Have you tried http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal" browser.

Comment: @UmairSaleem it seems your suggestion is a simpler way to do the job. i'll try that first. will let you know if it works. thank you. :)

Comment: @UmairSaleem unfortunately, i'm limited only to use httpClient,,

Answer (score 0):

Try [htmlunit.sourceforge.net](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net)

```
@Test
public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

    // Change the value of the text field
    textField.setValueAttribute("root");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Here is getting start link http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: unfortunately, i'm limited only to use httpClient